# I need to know how to swap SOL programmatically through Raydium using Javascript/Typescript

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

Hello i want to ask that how I can swap SOL to any token programmatically?.

I am new to Solana and am facing many challenges, being used to full ABI support in Solidity.

As an example Let's say I want to swap "SOL" with Token A on Raydium. How would I do this? A guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [repository](https://github.com/abbylow/raydium-swap) for an example of how to implement a raydium swap using the [raydium-sdk](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk).

Note that this is not an endorsement of the correctness of the linked repo, and you should DEFINITELY not use it in a production setting.