# Performing a swap

Tags: web3.js, swap, dex

I am clueless on how to perform a swap (ex. USDT to USDC) on the Solana blockchain on Raydium with code. I am currently using @solana/web3 and also not too familiar when it comes to programming. Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to know how to swap SOL programmatically through Raydium using Javascript/Typescript](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8552/i-need-to-know-how-to-swap-sol-programmatically-through-raydium-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Its quite ambitious to jump that far into things as making a swap on Solana is quite a bit tougher than on other chains. But there are three (that I know of) methods:

1. Use the SDK
2. Use the IDL and Anchor
3. Build the tx manually

I suggest googling "raydium idl github" and in their repo they have a good example that performs a swap in and swap back out using the v4 amm IDL. Work on getting that running and go from there.

Comment: I tried for some time using the SDK, but got nowhere. From what I've searched there is not a lot of information on a step by step instruction for performing a swap.

Answer (score 0):

If you like make a swap in Solana and u're using @solana/web3 them the next step is implement @solana/spl-token and [spl-token-swap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/spl-token-swap?activeTab=readme).

You can try swap instruction:

```
const swapInstruction = TokenSwap.swapInstruction(
  tokenSwapStateAccount,
  swapAuthority,
  userPublicKey,
  userTokenA,
  poolTokenA,
  poolTokenB,
  userTokenB,
  poolMint,
  feeAccount,
  null,
  TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  amount * 10 ** MintInfoTokenA.decimals,
  0
)

transaction.add(swapInstruction)
```

This is a complete [guide](https://www.soldev.app/course/token-swap) about how to use token-swap package.

Comment: what is the value of tokenSwapStateAccount in this ?

Comment: The guide link is not opening. Can you help me with a detailed example ?